# I cant create true android soap web service request

Tags: android, web-services, android-service, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am trying to connect this web-service

but when ı start, service not response,not coming any answer.

I can call another services with my codes but this some different

because after method name there is `<tem:request>` and I thing my request not correct

if anybody help thanks

```
<soapenv:Header/>    <soapenv:Body>
       <tem:GetCityList>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <tem:request>
             <ver:discardHistoryLoggingField>true</ver:discardHistoryLoggingField>
             <ver:callIDField>123</ver:callIDField>
             <ver:cardNumberField>123</ver:cardNumberField>
             <ver:channelIDField>123</ver:channelIDField>
             <ver:customerNumberField>123</ver:customerNumberField>
             <ver:dateField>06/10/11 15:24:17</ver:dateField>
             <ver:deviceBrandField>12</ver:deviceBrandField>
             <ver:deviceModelField>ios</ver:deviceModelField>
             <ver:deviceOSField>ios</ver:deviceOSField>
             <ver:deviceTypeField>sum</ver:deviceTypeField>
             <ver:iPNoField>111111122</ver:iPNoField>
             <ver:idField>3</ver:idField>
             <ver:phoneNumberField>5415132442</ver:phoneNumberField>
             <ver:userCodeField>23</ver:userCodeField>
          </tem:request>
       </tem:GetCityList>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**This is my service and there is all parametr inside another request tag. my codes**

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

             PropertyInfo fromProp =new PropertyInfo();
                 fromProp.setName("discardHistoryLoggingField");
                 fromProp.setValue(true);
                 fromProp.setType(String.class);
                 request.addProperty(fromProp);

                 PropertyInfo toProp6 =new PropertyInfo();
                 toProp6.setName("deviceOSField");
                 toProp6.setValue("Java");
                 toProp6.setType(String.class);
                 request.addProperty(toProp6);

                // countune to create property...

                 PropertyInfo toProp8 =new PropertyInfo();
                 toProp8.setName("userCodeField");
                 toProp8.setValue("0");
                 toProp8.setType(String.class);
                 request.addProperty(toProp8);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             try{ 

                 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            webResponse = response.toString();
```

somethings here

**Request not true so nothing happening when I run app**

Answer (score 0):

You're using org.ksoap2 library? If so..and your webservice is built in asp.net...

Them try to do this three things...and say if you have success:

Verify the webservice NAMESPACE. It have to be exactly the same.

I develope a asp.net webservice access by android too, and magicaly when i dont put a '/' on final of service url, nothing happens...put in your code this final char '/' on service url.

And finally, concat the webservice page extension if that is the case, like this:

```
new HttpTransportSE(URL.concat(".asmx"))
```